# What do you call words that are misspelled to add effect?

Tags: orthography

The most obvious example I can think of is the Mortal Kombat series. They replace almost all hard sounding C's with the letter 'K'. A couple other examples off the top of my head are 'Froot Loops', 'The Beatles', the Red Hot Chili Peppers album 'Blood Sugar Sex Magik'. There's a tonne more. I'm just wondering if there's a proper term for these types of words.

Comment: I don't think "The Beatles" is even remotely in the same ballpark as the rest. It's a word play, a pun. *Magik* and *Froot* are not.

Comment: Yes, I agree, "The Beatles" is more of a play on words than deliberate misspelling.

Comment: Of note, I have heard that _Froot Loops_ are spelled that way to dodge a legal issue involving a product labeled _Fruit_ not actually containing fruit.

Comment: @MrHen, yeah I've heard that too. Also with the use of *chocolaty* instead of *chocolate* for foods not actually containing chocolate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm amazed there is actually a term for this.

Yes, there is a name. It's

> *Sensational Spelling*: Sensational spelling is the deliberate spelling of a word in an incorrect or non-standard way for special effects.
>
> Sensational spellings are common in advertising and product placement. In particular, brand names...

[[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensational_spelling)]