# What is the word and/or process used to describe mashing two words together or inserting phonetic sounds to create new written words?

Tags: etymology, synonyms, portmanteau-words, blending

### The question

[Portmanteau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portmanteau) seems to apply in cases like:

- **Phablet** - Bigger than a smart phone, smaller than a tablet.
- **Smog** - Smoke and fog.
- **Vlog** - Video and blog.

There must be another word for things that have a more phonetic feel:

- **Shizzle** - recently added to the OED, which sort of feels like sure with fizzle in it?

Or for a word that has one letter replaced by another letter or letters, but where the pronunciation stays the same:

- **Comix** - Web comics?

Comment: [What do you call words that are misspelled to add effect?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33966/what-do-you-call-words-that-are-misspelled-to-add-effect/33968#33968) and [What is it called when words are deliberately spelled incorrectly but pronunciation is kept unchanged?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46101/what-is-it-called-when-words-are-deliberately-spelled-incorrectly-but-pronunciat) address the second question.

Comment: [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/shizzle) has: '**shizzle**: (US, slang)
(1) _adjective_ 
See fo' shizzle / 
_(2) noun_
a form of slang popularized by US rap musicians in which the trailing syllables of certain words are replaced by the suffix -izzle / Word Origin
C21: a phonetic blend of sure + izzle'. So, a _phonetic blend_ – but no evidence of 'fizzle' (as opposed to say 'drizzle').

Comment: Thanks @EdwinAshworth,  Found what I was looking for in the second link:           A general term for intentionally altered spelling is __sensational spelling__, in which the writer misspells words for an intended effect.

Another, more specific term is __cacography__, which is misspelling intended for comic effect. It was often seen used to mock illiterate/uneducated people.

Answer (score 1):

The word is portmanteau. I found this: "Portmanteau word "word blending the sound of two different words" (1882), coined by "Lewis Carroll" (Charles L. Dodgson, 1832-1898) for the sort of words he invented for "Jabberwocky," on notion of "two meanings packed up into one word." As a noun in this sense from 1872." on Dictionary.com after stumbling across it in Wikipedia. MY word would be "combiage"= combine+verbiage
As far as the new words that would be neologism as defined by MW: 
Simple Definition of neologism

```
: a new word or expression or a new meaning of a word
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a portmanteau; a formal example of one is brunch (breakfast + lunch), whereas a more informal example is skort (skirt + shorts).

Comment: What is comix?  a combination of comic and sex? And Shizzle, what is that a combination of?