# Term for wordplay where a new spelling is made up for an existing word

Tags: single-word-requests, orthography, homophones, homonyms

I am familiar with homographs and homophones (and homonyms), but there is a different type of "word play" or "spelling play" I've seen come up as of recently that I'm trying to find out if there is a name for. Or if one for it simply just doesn't exist.

There's a few examples I could list, but the best one I could think of is "kaiyote". This is obviously a play on the real word, "coyote". However, it's not considered a homograph or homophone because the word "kaiyote" in itself doesn't have any meaning — it's just a word spelled to make it sound like the actual real word "coyote".

Could anyone tell me if there is any term for this type of practice?

Comment: Right. I didn't say "stand for" though. I said it's a play on the word/spelling.

Comment: It's an alternative spelling, like *thru* or *kwik*.

Comment: Related posts: [What do you call words that are misspelled to add effect?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33966), [What is it called when words are deliberately spelled incorrectly but pronunciation is kept unchanged?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46101)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it's just a word spelled to make it sound like the actual real word *coyote*

You're probably looking for [**sensational spelling**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensational_spelling):

> Sensational spelling is the deliberate spelling of a word in an incorrect or non-standard way for special effect.

Wikipedia goes on to give several examples, some of which are brand names (Froot Loops), but it also mentions a number of band names including:

- The Beatles
- the Byrds
- Led Zeppelin